# How to healthcheck redis with tls enabled

Tags: c#, redis

I have Redis Cache implemented in my application. Currently my dev environment does not require ssl and tls enabled but my production envirnment does. Those are the two main differences between my environments.

My dev environment health check is reporting back healthy. When deployed to prod, my health check is coming back unhealthy. May I ask how do I enhance my healthcheck to take into consideration TLS for redis?

The health check code

```
.AddRedis(x => "awsredis-test.com:6379",
          name: "REDIS",
          failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
          tags: new[] { "redis" })
```

I also tried awsredis-test.com:6379,sslprotocols = tls12 and it didn't work on production.